# What is the current monetary value of ten thousand talents and a hundred denarii in US Dollars?

Tags: matthew

Matthew 18: 24 And when he had begun to settle accounts, one was brought to him who owed him ten thousand talents.

Matthew 18: 28 “But that servant went out and found one of his fellow servants who owed him a hundred denarii; and he laid hands on him and took him by the throat, saying, ‘Pay me what you owe!’

Answer (score 3):

Based on footnotes from the New Living Translation Bible, 10,000 talents is roughly 375 tons of silver. Silver today is about $20.69/troy ounce. With about 29,166 troy ounces in a ton, **ten thousand talents would be around $226,291,702.50.**

A denarii is considered a days wage in the resources I've come across be them footnotes or Bible dictionaries. No hard and fast silver or gold amounts. So you could see it as **a 100 days worth of work**.

The force of this parable is this is a debt that the debtor would never hope to pay in his lifetime (in their money in that day or in ours today), and the forgiveness was given so freely that his lack of forgiveness was a stark contrast to his master's. This is powerful parable of the need for forgiveness and the consequences of not mimicking the master's forgiveness in our dealings.

Comment: To add to this, it is also a statement of how the sins another person has committed against me are as nothing compared to the sins I have committed against God.

Answer (score 0):

In his resourceful book entitled “HALLEY’S BIBLE HANDBOOK, 1965, page 442”, Dr. Henry H. Halley (author, minister, and Bible lecturer) wrote the following in relation to the Dollar equivalent of a talent and a dinarii (pence or shilling), and the message behind the verses:

“A talent was about $1000. A pence or shilling was about 17 cents. The man was forgiven $10,000,000, but was unwilling to forgive $17. That is Jesus’ comparison of our own sins against God to those sinned against us. Notice Jesus’ statement that there is no hope of forgiveness unless we forgive.”